# How to make Button Chips gradient in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget

linear-gradient(133.07deg, #136A8A 0%, #267871 98.55%)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use [LinearGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html)
For using linear gradient you need to know :

- Gradient colour in hex
- The direction (like at your example it's from top-left to bottom-right and to say it to Flutter, it'll be from topLeft bottomRight)

The code code example:

```
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
            Color(0x136A8A),
            Color(0x267871),
          ],
        ),
     ),
   )
```

Comment: It's work I have tried this as well, although I want to keep the original press effect of ActionChips so this is the least solution I want to implemented

Comment: Use InkWell widget it adds ripple effect